# Sum by day, sum by month, sum by year, all in 1 table in Athena/Presto

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

Tasks:
Count Distinct Members and Sum Miles

1. members & miles earned by day
2. members & miles earned by week
3. members & miles earned by month

One single table of all the above 3, and with a label saying which table they are i.e. structure will be like:

```
date       | members | miles earned  | category
01/05/2019 |   1000  |          2000 | 'Daily'
01/05/2019 | 30,000  | 2,500,000,000 | 'Monthly'
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: How is your data represented?